# for loop with if statement to compare matrices and fill new matrix

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, matrix

I have two matrices, matrix A and matrix B (5 x 5).
I randomly assigned values between 0 and 4 to matrix A.

Now, for example, I want to check if A[1,2] > A[2,1]. If that holds true I want to assign a specific value to B[1,2] and B[2,1].
In this case it should be B[1,2] = 3 and B[2,1] = 0.
If A[1,2] < A[2,1] it should be the other way around; e.g. B[1,2] = 0 and B[2,1] = 3.
If A[1,2] == A[2,1] it should be B[1,2] = 1 and B[2,1] = 1.

I am looking for an R code to do this as a loop to fill matrix B completely with the right values of either 0,1 or 3.

I would really appreciate any help! Thank you very much in advance!

[image: Matrix A]

If the outcome of R is matrix A, matrix B should look like the self-drawn matrix.

[image: Matrix B]

Comment: Hi student_s,

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe to make this question a bit clearer you can provide an example... maybe a smaller (3x3?) Matrix representing A and B so it's a little more obvious in general what you're trying to accomplish. Right now I can't tell what you want, for example, B[2,3] or B[3,2] to look like. 

Also, `for` loops are great, but you might check out the `apply` family of functions in R, these are often very efficient (in R) for problems like this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I added two images to hopefully make it a little bit more visual. I want to simulate football games. In fact, matrix A should represent the goals scored and matrix B should represent the points each team got based on the goals scored in matrix A. I hope this also helps to clarify my issue.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 1):

We can do like this

```
> `diag<-`(3 * (A > t(A)) + 1 * (A == t(A)), NA)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA    3    0
[2,]    0   NA    1
[3,]    3    1   NA
```